# is it OK to handle a Core Data database created with from an UIManagedDocument with NSFileManager?

Tags: ios, database, core-data, uimanageddocument

I'm making an app which uses **Core Data**, and for the purpose of my app I need to **bundle a pre-populated database** with the app bundle.

**I'm using a `UIManagedDocument`**

For this, I created the database with the app and later loaded the data. Then I searched the iOS Simulator folder in my Mac and drag and dropped the `persistentStore` file into the app bundle.

Later in the code I copied it to the `NSDocumentDirectory` because the user will be allowed to edit the database at runtime. This was done with the following method:

```
if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[self.appDatabase.fileURL path]])
{        
    // COPY FROM BUNDLE

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *DB = [[paths lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Default App Database"];
    DB = [DB stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"StoreContent"];

    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:DB withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error];

    NSLog(@"create directory error: %@",error);

    DB = [DB stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];

    NSString *shippedDB = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"persistentStore"];
    NSLog(@"%d",[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:shippedDB]);
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:shippedDB toPath:DB error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Copy error %@",error);
}
```

Everything is working perfectly! But, I'm not sure if this will generate some type of error. So my question, **is it OK to handle a Core Data database created with from an UIManagedDocument with NSFileManager?**

And, **will Apple complain in the review process for bundling the `persistentStore` file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling a default persistent store with the app is explicitly mentioned in the "Core Data Programming Guide":

> How do I initialize a store with default data?
>
> ...
>
> You can create a separate persistent store that contains the default
>   data and include the store as an application resource. When you want
>   to use it, you must either copy the whole store to a suitable
>   location, or copy the objects from the defaults store to an existing
>   store.